# What does the phrase " happen to be " mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the phrase "happen to be" mean in the sentence:

> Camera just happen to be recording this.

Comment: *Cameras **just happen to be** recording this* is really just a stylised way of saying *Cameras **are** recording this* - with the implication that whatever ***happens to be*** the case is just a matter of blind chance that could easily have been otherwise (i.e. - oftentimes, cameras *wouldn't* be recording it). The specific word ***just*** there is simply an optional ***intensifier*** (it *really, **really*** IS nothing more than "chance").

Comment: @FumbleFingers That looks like a complete answer to me!

Comment: @TypeIA: No need - it's been asked and answered before.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then your close vote and link to the duplicate is more appropriate.

Comment: More appropriate than what? Are you objecting to the fact of me enlightening the OP in a comment?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes: answers in comments are discouraged on SE. If it's a duplicate, vote to close, as you did, and there's no need for an answer-in-comment. If it's not, you can post a proper answer. I just wanted to mention it because I think you answer-in-comment a lot. I'm occasionally guilty of it too, and trying to improve.

Comment: @TypeIA: I can't deny that. But in my defence, my "answer in comment" is often / usually associated with a closevote. In this case, as I recall, I made a mistake and found a "duplicate" on ELU rather than on ELL. But then I got distracted and never successfully repeated the dup search on the right site until after your comment "pinged" me to come back here. And I do quite often expand on an initial comment to post an actual answer some time later, if I notice that no-one else has done so, so I don't think I'm all that bad for the site! :)